# How to Display Text along with JQuery Progressbar and forward to some other JSP page after completing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have progress bar. I t is working fine but I need to display some text along with the progress bar & when it reaches 100% it should forward a jsp page. This is my program which increases by 10% & I want to print some text like:

- 10% -> Uploading Personal Details
- 20% -> Checking Email ID.
- 30% -> Generating user ID.

   ....
  And it is important that after it reaches 100% it must be forward to some.jsp. How to achieve this. Please suggest. This is my program:

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
      <script type='text/javascript'>
         var progress = setInterval(function() {
         var $bar = $('.bar');

           if ($bar.width()==400) {
             clearInterval(progress);
             $('.progress').removeClass('active');
           } else {
             $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
           }
           $bar.text($bar.width()/4 + "%");
         }, 800);
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
          <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

  In mystyle.css:

  ```
  @import url('css/bootstrap.css');

  .container {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 400px;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do redirection with Javascript using `window.location.replace`

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com/finishedLoading");
```

You will have to keep track of your progress, and depending on that, display the message. Once finished, do the redirect.

Based on your example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var progress = setInterval(function() {
    var $bar = $('.bar');

    if ($bar.width()==400) {
        clearInterval(progress);
        $('.progress').removeClass('active');
        window.location.replace("http://example.com/finishedLoading");
    } else {
        $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
        switch($bar.width()){
            case 40: $("#status").html("Uploading Personal Details"); break;
            case 80: $("#status").html("Checking Email ID"); break;
            case 120: $("#status").html("Generating user ID"); break;
             // other case statements...
            case 400: $("#status").html("Finished"); break;
        }
    }
    $bar.text($bar.width()/4 + "%");
  }, 800);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="progress progress-striped active">
       <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <span id="status">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The progress here is direct kept in the `$bar.width()`.

Comment: Please give me the complete example.I can't understand. How does I Know its complete. I mean in exactly where should I place the call & how? Tell me about text also.

Comment: I changed the example. I adapted yours now.

Comment: Thank You so much. Really you are genius. It perfectly works.